# Build mongo hex object ID from its components e.g. timestamp,. counter, random value

Tags: mongodb

I have a program that marshals the mongo BSON to JSON, where the mongo object ID is represented by its components:

```
"id": {
    "date": 1487703734000,
    "timestamp": 1487703734,
    "counter": 14046291,
    "processIdentifier": 24019,
    "machineIdentifier": 6597369,
    "timeSecond": 1487703734,
    "time": 1487703734000
  }
```

Can I convert this into the hexadecimal mongo ID? I can see in [the mongo object ID docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) how it is composed, but I'm not sure if I have what they are referring to as the "random value" in my JSON. (appears I do have the timestamp and counter though)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Was that answer helpful? Could you approve upvote if so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using any supported drivers. **You can use 5 byte random value(3 byte machine id and 2 byte processId)**. You can [refer this](https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/learn-structure-objectid-mongodb/#:%7E:text=An%20ObjectId%20in%20MongoDB%20is,ObjectId%20represent%20the%20process%20ID.) It has nice explanation.

Here are java and python options.

You can do it using [java driver](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/latest/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html). But it is deprecated.

> ObjectId​(Date date, int machineIdentifier, short processIdentifier, int counter)

There is no way using mongodb commands. Every programming language which supports mongo have an option to generate `objectId` but all may not have this particular option.

`python` has an option. [Reference](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html)

> By default, ObjectId() creates a new unique identifier. The optional parameter oid can be an ObjectId, or any 12 bytes or, in Python 2, any 12-character str.
>
> For example, the 12 bytes b’foo-bar-quux’ do not follow the ObjectId specification but they are acceptable input:
>
> ObjectId(b'foo-bar-quux') =>
> ObjectId('666f6f2d6261722d71757578')

> > but I'm not sure if I have what they are referring to as the "random value" in my JSON

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was also looking for the api or package in python to generate back the ObjectId back from the given components. I am sharing the function which I created after exploring the bson documentation and code.
This function will return the ObjectId string.

```
import struct
import binascii
from bson.py3compat import PY3, bytes_from_hex, string_type, text_type

def get_object_id_str(timestamp=None,randomValue1=None,randomValue2=None,counter=None):
    oid=None
    oid = struct.pack(">i", int(timestamp))
    oid += struct.pack(">I", randomValue1)[1:]
    oid += struct.pack(">H", abs(randomValue2))
    oid += struct.pack(">i", counter)[1:4]

    if PY3:
        result = binascii.hexlify(oid).decode()
    else:
        result=binascii.hexlify(oid)
    return result
```

Example:
timestamp: 1618752785
machineID/randomValue1: 16171515
processID/randomValue2: 21753
counter: 1066714

for ObjectId: 607c3511f6c1fb54f91046da